# dipslaying website/webpage in a control

Tags: .net, asp.net

i am working on a page where user will enter the url and hit enter to display the web site... so i am not sure which control will serve the best. any help?

so something like this:

`textbox _www.cnn.com____________`

display the web site here ......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `onkeypress` event and call a JS function where you can check whether the Enter key was hit, then set the url to `Window.Location` e.g.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onkeypress="OpenURL();"></asp:TextBox>

function OpenURL()
{
if(window.event.keyCode == 13)
{
    window.location = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>').value;
}
}
```

**Edit:**After reading your comments, now I understand correctly what you are looking for; you can use the Iframe control of html http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_iframe.asp

Comment: i am not looking for js to do, my question is what control to use in order to display the webpage.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an iFrame.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

But some people really hate them.

Comment: i am one of those people who really hate iframe, so there is no such control? there should be a way wihtout using iframe..hmmm